# Why does Taylor’s series “work”?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematics, analyticity

I am an undergraduate Physics student completing my first year shortly. The following question is based on the physical systems I’ve encountered so far. (We mostly did Newtonian mechanics.)

In all of our analyses of the physical systems (up till now) we recklessly exploited Taylor’s series, retaining terms up to the desired precision of our approximate model of reality.

But what is the justification of using Taylor’s series? It implicitly implies that the mathematical functions in our physical model are **analytic**. But how can we be sure about that?

Sure, the nature doesn’t seem to be *discontinuous* or have “kinks” *(i.e. nonexistent derivatives)* in its behaviour. That seems plausible. But still, there are ***non-analytic smooth*** functions. And there are *“many”* more of them than there are analytic functions. So even if the nature works smoothly in its endeavours, it is essentially *zero* probability that it should do so analytically.

So why do we use Taylor’s series at all?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1324/2451 and [links therein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1324?lq=1).

Comment: What is a "non-analytical smooth" function? Any smooth function can be described by an analytical recipe (maybe with many, many terms, but that's another issue - and possibly one reason for the Taylor series simplification)

Comment: @Steeven a function by definition is analytical when it is equal to its Taylor series. This is rare in the same sense that rational numbers are rare among the reals

Comment: @Steeven  if every smooth function would be analytic, then you can reconstruct whole function from its knowledge on arbitrary small interval. Intuitively this is nosense. Famous example is function for which $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ if $x>0$

Comment: Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400379/why-is-analyticity-a-good-mathematical-assumption-in-general-relativity).

Comment: "it is essentially zero probability that it should do so analytically" - this assumes a probability measure on the space of all functions which is somehow "natural". While there are several important measures with this property, choosing one of them is still a human prejudice.

Comment: Be careful with how you think of probability. If I throw a pencil on the ground, there is infinitesimally small probability that it lands pointing at any specific angle (since angles are continuous), and yet it does so every time.

Comment: @Umaxo I don't find it intuitively obvious that knowing the values on an open interval, together with knowing that it is smooth, would be insufficient to extend the function over the whole real line.

Comment: @Acccumulation doesn't matter, intuition is not rigorous proof, is often misleading and is subjective anyway. But the fact is, you can construct smooth nonanalytic functions like the one i have shown. You can even construct function that is smooth but is not analytic in any point on real axis.

Comment: @Umaxo I was responding to your claim that "intuitively this is [nonsense]".

Comment: Nature has "kinks" or discontinuities in various phase transitions, just to bring this to your attention

Comment: Might be good question for more math oriented site.

Comment: Why asking about Taylor series specifically. The question is why is there an Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences
: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences

Comment: @Steeven Here's an everywhere smooth function that's nowhere analytic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had this same problem, too. The trick with it is realizing that there's an important difference between Taylor *series* and Taylor *approximations* or *polynomials*, whose behavior is described by Taylor's *theorem*. Yes, very often I suspect a common mistake is that you first see Taylor polynomials and theorem, and then you get Taylor series and that becomes the focus and suddenly you forget about the rest.

But here, what we're actually doing when we "truncate" a Taylor series is that we are going back to a Taylor *polynomial*, since that is what a truncated Taylor series is - or alternatively, a Taylor series is the natural extension of to infinite order. In that context, Taylor's *theorem* tells you exactly how it does or does not behave as an approximation and - surprise - it doesn't require anything about analyticity at all. Analyticity *only* comes into play when you consider the *full* series: in fact, what Taylor's theorem tells you is that a finite Taylor polynomial *will still work* as an approximation for even a *non*-analytic function, so long as you get suitably close to the point at which you're taking the polynomial and the function is differentiable enough to be able to make the polynomial of the given degree possible to take.

Specifically, Taylor's theorem tells you that, analytic *or not*, if you cut the Taylor series so that the highest term has degree $N$, to form the Taylor polynomial (or truncated Taylor series) $T_N(a, x)$, where $a$ is the expansion point, you have

$$f(x) = T_N(a, x) + o(|x - a|^N),\ \ \ \ \ x \rightarrow a$$

where the last part defines the behavior of the remainder term: this is the "little-o notation" and means that the error pales in comparison to the bound $|x - a|^N$.

As an example in elementary mathematical physics, consider the analysis of the "pathological" potential in Newtonian mechanics given by

$$U(x) := \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},\ x \ne 0\\ 0,\ \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

which is smooth *everywhere*, but *not* analytic when $x = 0$. In particular, it is so bad that not only is it not analytic, the Taylor series exists and even *converges* ... just to the *wrong thing!*:

$$U(x)\ "="\ 0 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3 + 0x^4 + \cdots,\ \ \ \ \mbox{near $x = 0$}$$

... and yes, that is literally 0s on *every term*, so the right-hand expression equals $0$!

(ADD - see comments: no... not *THAT* 0! ... uh ... Ooops... uhhh ... )

*Nonetheless*, while that is technically "wrong", the usual analysis methods you have for this system will still tell you the "right thing", provided you're *careful*: in particular, we note that $x = 0$ looks like some kind of "equilibrium" since $U'$ is zero there, *but* we also note that we are told - correctly! - that we should not apply the harmonic oscillator approximation *because* we also have that the coefficient out in front of $x^2$ is 0 as well.

We are justified in both conclusions because while this Taylor *series* is "bad", it is still A-OK by Taylor's *theorem* to write the truncated series, and thus Taylor *polynomial*,

$$U(x) \approx 0 + 0x + 0x^2,\ \ \ \ \mbox{near $x = 0$}$$

even though it "equals $0$", because this $U(x)$ is "so exquisitely approximated by the constant function $U^{*}(x) := 0$" that it is $o(|x|^N)$ for *every* order $N > 0$ and thus, in particular, also $N = 2$! Hence, the harmonic analysis and conclusion of failure thereof are *still* 100% justified!

---

**ADD** (IE+1936.6817 Ms - 2018-05-16): Per a comment added below, there is an additional wrinkle in this story which had been thinking of mentioning but didn't, yet for which, in light of that, I thought maybe I now should.

There are actually two different kinds of ways in which the Taylor series can fail when a function is not analytic at a point and it is taken at that point. One of these is the way I showed above - where the Taylor series converges, but it converges to the "wrong" thing in that it does not equal the function in any non-trivial interval around that point (you *might* be able to have it equal it on some weird dusty/broken-up set, but not on any interval), i.e. no interval $[a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon]$ with $\epsilon \ne 0$. Such a point is called a *Cauchy point*, or *C-point*.

The other way is for the Taylor series to have actually radius of convergence 0, i.e. it does not *converge* in any non-trivial interval of the same form with $\epsilon \ne 0$. This kind of point is called a *Pringsheim point*, or *P-point*. This case was not demonstrated, but even in such a case, the Taylor series is still an *asymptotic series* in the sense that it will at least try to *start* to converge if you're close enough and, moreover, the closer you are to the expansion point $a$, the more terms you can take before it stops converging and starts to diverge again. Since in physics, we are usually interested - and esp. for the harmonic oscillator - in only a few low-order terms, the ultimate behavior of the series is not important and we can still take it to get, say, the harmonic approximation near a point of equilibrium even if the function is not analytic there - e.g. consider the potential $U_3(x) := U(x) + \frac{1}{2} kx^2$ with $k > 0$, where we used the first potential we just gave above. This is not analytic at $x = 0$ either, but nonetheless, the harmonic approximation will not only work, but work exquisitely well, and with the frequency $\omega := \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ as usual.

See:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620290/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-smooth-everywhere-analytic-nowhere-yet-tay

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "so the right-hand expression equals 0!" No, it does not equal `0! = 1`. :P

Comment: @Fabian Röling : Uh, no, it should be 0. $U(0) = 0$, and it's super flat around that zero input value. Keep in mind that exponent is $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, not $-x^2$, so that means it is effectively _minus infinity_ at $x = 0$.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Just one thing. Where were you told to not apply harmonic oscillator approximation (which is just Taylor’s series truncated to second order) when the coefficient of $x^2$ equals $0$?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer /r/UnexpectedFactorial

Comment: @Cubic : Hah! :)

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Are you looking at my comment? 

Comment: @Atom : Well, you _could_, I suppose, say it is approximable with a harmonic oscillator with spring constant 0: effectively, the particle is "very free" about this particular point. However, the problem there is that the asymptotic behavior of this well is then not distinguished from, say, $U_2(x) := x^4$, so I'm not sure that "counts".

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Oh yea, of course! But $U_2(x)=x^4$ behaviour is also periodic, close to harmonic in fact — I just plotted it on WolframAlpha.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer And though I can see why you shouldn’t approximate your $U(x)$ as a *harmonic oscillator*. But it does not in any way seem to justify why you shouldn’t use Taylor’s series at all.

Comment: @Atom : I didn't say you couldn't. In fact, the answer was to show that you _could_, even in a nonanalytic case, because you're always truncating at a finite number of terms in such analyses. Effectively, the Taylor series always gives you the "local" behavior of any smooth function, in the "best possible" way. It's just that for certain functions - i.e. analytic functions - you get the boon that it also gives you more!

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Absolutely gotcha! Thanks a ton!

Comment: As a supporting point for using Taylor series approximations, the most popular way to convert between continuous (Laplace domain) and discrete (Z domain) transfer functions is by using the bilinear transform, which uses only the first two terms of a Maclaurin series as a "good enough" approximation.  Higher-order terms in the series can certainly be used to refine the result, but in practise they rarely are.

Comment: A useful exercise is to take a known value that can be described by a Taylor expansion and see how many coefficients you need to solve for before the error becomes unimportant. In undergraduate physics, it's often not many (like 2 or 3)

Comment: Just one small caveat (I'm a mathematician, so allow me to be pedantic): one of the problem with non-analytic functions is that the interval in which the Taylor approximation is valid typically decreases very quickly as $N$ increases, so some care still needs to be taken to check that the approximation we're making is valid in the range of values of $x$ we are interested in.

Comment: @Denis Nardin : Thanks. Had thought of that, but didn't think to add it. Added.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to annotate edits. Revision history is persistent and public, complete with timestamps and everything.

Comment: What does it mean for a series to start to converge, or to stop converging and start diverging?

Comment: @LSpice : The error term decreases for a while in the beginning, then starts increasing again, never to come back.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer, right, I forgot that we had a specific limit to which we were trying to converge, so that there was a well defined notion of the error term.  Thanks!

Comment: Great answer -- do you have a reference for the terms "Cauchy point" and "Pringsheim point"? I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Pallavi Sudhir : That was what was used in the articles cited in the answer I was given for the linked question. Though they could just abbreviate it as "C-point" and "P-point", respectively.

Answer (score 23):

[The Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says that any continuous function on a compact interval is arbitrarily well approximated by polynomials. Thus, as long as we're only interested in explaining experimental results (and not in the *exact* solutions of theoretical models), series expansions are plenty good enough. That is, for whatever we'd like to describe, there is a model (at least in the statistics sense) which describes it to any good enough accuracy and which is analytic. So it doesn't seem obvious that we'll ever be able to tell whether the world is analytic or just $C^\infty$, or even $C^0$!

Of course in practice, our theories make infinitely many predictions for the values of such functions, for instance mechanics predicts them as solutions to differential equations, field theory by some integrals. Typically we cannot evaluate our theoretical predictions exactly and so we use numerics or asymptotic series methods. Things that come out of our models tend not to be analytic, so I think we're a bit spoiled in our physics education with all these analytic and solvable models.

The question of why so many (but not all!) exact solutions to theoretical models are real or even complex analytic is a whole different discussion, and much more mysterious, although [causality does have some bear on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations). For instance, response functions in time always have an extension to complex time in the upper-half-plane.

But more mysteriously, there are things like the KdV equation, the first equation to describe solitons, [whose integrability turned out to be closely related to elliptic curves](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-54). So integrability seems not just related to analyticity, but even to algebraicity! But it is a rather hidden connection, because the solutions to KdV themselves are transcendental. Anyway, I do recommend the book I linked. It's written for undergraduates and it's a lot of fun.

Comment: but this polynamial will not in general be the same as taylor expansion around some point. So it doesn't explain why taylor expansion is so broadly used.

Comment: @Umaxo It doesn't really matter, so long as we keep track of our errors. Taylor's theorem says that as you take more terms, the approximation gets better. One could in principle use some other sort of approximating polynomial, such as the Bernstein polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial . The point is because the function has a good analytic (even polynomial!) approximation, its Taylor series will be well-behaved.

Comment: @RyanThorngren I think that answers my question. But why is the exact solutions to theoretical models being analytic is *much more* mysterious? Doesn’t that follow from *us* approximating the solutions *using* analytic functions in the first place?

Comment: @Atom I suppose there's two questions to ask, 1. why are the mechanical and other laws so simple? For instance, the equations of motion in rigid-body mechanics are all second order differential equations. If this is an approximation to reality, it is certainly a very good one. And 2. why are exactly-solvable models so useful? The solution to most mechanical problems will be chaotic, and not analytic, but still so many things we ecounter have an exactly solvable version that we can learn from. (There are exceptions though, like turbulence.) For these models we really do write the exact solution

Comment: @RyanThorngren Don’t the systems which you say *exactly solvable* rely upon the assumption that there **is** an analytic solution to those systems in the first place?

Comment: @Ryan Thorngren that is not true. The approximation gets better only for analytic functions, not nonanalytic ones. F.e. take the famous $f(x)=0;x\le 0$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/x};x >0$ on the domain $x \in [-2,2]$. The taylor series around, for example, point $x=1$ will get closer and closer to $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ on the whole compact domain and will fail to be zero for all points $x<0$. The polynom from SW theorem will be different and taylor expansion cannot be used

Comment: @Umaxo I agree with you. What I meant is a little bit different. The point is that the bump function does have good approximation by analytic functions (eg. polynomials) whose Taylor series does converge. I mean that whatever the system actually does, we can approximate it analytically.

Comment: @Atom Whether the solution is analytic or not is whatever comes out of the equations. They typically have unique solutions once the boundary conditions are specified, and that solution is often analytic.

Comment: @RyanThorngren What I’m asking is this: In the formulation (from which uniqueness and other things are derived) of those exactly solvable models, didn’t we assume beforehand the analytic nature of the model?

Comment: @Atom Yes it's true, we did just invent the model, and it cannot have any claim to exact accuracy. Nonetheless, these models give us a pretty good understanding of what we see in some experiments (even though the models we can exactly solve are quite rare!).

Comment: @RyanThorngren So I think it would be better to delete the second paragraph of your answer. Cuz our assumptions of an analytic nature of the models just happened to match with the experimental observations and gave us *good enough* (if not *exactly precise*) power to predict. And due to experimental errors, we can *never* be 100% sure whether our analytic solutions even in what we call *exactly solvable* models describe nature *exactly*.

Comment: @Atom I don't think that's quite right. We did not assume analyticity, perhaps only smoothness. Even if we cannot exactly describe the physical law, it is still curious that analyticity appears in so many of our attempts to.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Thanks! But are you sure that we *didn’t* assume analyticity?

Comment: @Atom Typically we only assume some degree of differentiability when we express the equations of motion (usually just twice differentiable since Newton's laws are second-order in derivatives). Analyticity falls out afterwards (sometimes).

Comment: @RyanThorngren Got it! Just one last request: Can you please point to me some resources which discuss this mystery of getting analytic solutions which you mentioned in second paragraph.

Comment: @RyanThorngren: One of the chief reasons that the functions are so simple is because the universe has a significant number of symmetries, and no origin or natural rotation. That means the laws must be invariant for the relevant transformations.

Answer (score 4):

If we know the value of $f$ at $t$, and we want to know the value of $f(t+\Delta t)$ for small $\Delta t$, then the most basic thing to do is to just assume that $f(t+\Delta t) = f(t)$. This is known as the "zeroth order approximation". In calculus, you learned about tangent lines. With a tangent line, instead of approximating the function with a fixed value, you approximate it with a line, and the slope of the line is the derivative: $f(t+\Delta t) = f(t)+(\Delta t) f'(t)$. This is the "first order approximation". So this is treating the derivative as a constant, i.e. a first order approximation of the function is given in term of a zeroth order approximation of the derivative.

We could instead calculate a first order approximation of the derivative, and use that to approximate the function. This would then be a second order approximation of the function. We have $f'(t+\Delta t) = f'(t) +(\Delta t)f''(t)$, and integrating that we get $f(t+\Delta t) = f(t)+(\Delta t)f'(t)+\frac {(\Delta t)^2}{2}f''(t)$. We can continue this process, and the nth order approximation will then simply be the first n (with zero indexing) terms of the Taylor Series. This isn't assuming that the function is analytic; it's simply applying an intuitive strategy to approximate the function.

So is it valid? Well, if we have a bound on the nth derivative of $f$ over the interval, then we can use that to put a bound on the (n-1)th derivative, which can then give a bound on the (n-2)th, and so. So even without knowing the $f$ is analytic, having a bound on the nth derivative gives a bound on the error for the nth order approximation.

Answer (score 3):

> So even if the nature works smoothly in its endeavours, it is
>   essentially zero probability that it should do so analytically

Where does this implication come from? Most equations that we use in physics are solved by functions that are indeed analytic: this is because most equations are differential up to some order and you can use Cauchy conditions to prove it. In those cases using expansions in power series is justified and you commit an error on the predictions proportional to whichever order you choose to stop at.

In some other cases functions are not analytic and in fact one does not apply such expansions blindly: there is a whole area of classical electrodynamics dealing with singularities in Green's functions and residual's theorem (just to mention one) or investigation of poles of the Lagrangians in QFT (to mention another one).

Answer (score 2):

Something additional you should be aware of:

In order to talk about analycity, you have to talk about derivatives, and in order to talk about derivatives, you need limits. In fact, even to talk about continuity, you need limits. And to talk about limits, you have to have things defined to infinite precision.

But the whole concepts by which physical values are defined break down when you push the accuracy too far. If you want to talk about the velocity of an object, you have to be able to define its position. But that requires an exact definition of what the object is. Real physical objects shed atoms to the environment and gain other atoms from it. At any one time, how do you decide exactly which atoms are part of your object and which are not? Most of your object is open space between those atoms. How do you define exactly where the boundary is between the open space that contributes to the volume of your object and the open space that is outside?

Beyond that, it is believed that there is a fundamental lower limit to measurable size: the Planck length. Nothing smaller can be measured (and currently, nothing a whole lot larger can be either). But limits cannot be defined with such a restriction. The definition of a limit admits no lower bound on how close you can get to the target. Thus it makes no sense to talk about limits involving physical measurements. And if you cannot talk about limits, you cannot talk about continuity or derivatives or analycity or Taylor series.

If you were to take the most comprehensive measurements of an object as it moves that are even theoretically possible, you would not end up with a well-defined mathematical function. Instead, you would end up with data having error ranges into which an infinite number of functions would fit. Among those functions will be some that are quite badly behaved - not continuous at any point. But also among those functions will be some that are analytic.

Any of these functions would provide an equally accurate description of your object's motion. The discontinuous functions are difficult to work with, but the analytic functions have excellent behavior. It's your choice. Which will you prefer to use?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Sympathiser's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/480187/) -- one can see why the existence of functions like $e^{-1/x}$ is not surprising by rephrasing them as "**functions that approach zero near zero faster than any polynomial**". This is not fundamentally more surprising than e.g. functions that grow faster than every polynomial -- in fact, for any function $f(x)$ that grows faster than every polynomial, the function $\frac1{f(1/x)}$ approaches zero near zero faster than any polynomial.

So for rapidly growing $f(x)=e^x$, one gets the corresponding smooth non-analytic $e^{-1/x}$. For $x^x$, one gets $x^{1/x}$. For $x!$, one gets $\frac{1}{(1/x)!}$, and so on.

See my post [**What's with e^(-1/x)? On smooth non-analytic functions: part I**](https://thewindingnumber.blogspot.com/2019/05/whats-with-e-1x-on-smooth-non-analytic.html) for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I see the core of your question being the statement:

> So even if the nature works smoothly in its endeavours, it is
>   essentially zero probability that it should do so analytically

This is besides the point. We:

- Observe phenomena
- Build models of these using analytic functions

  - Mostly because it is easier
- Use maths to analyse those and create predictions
- Test those predictions
- If those predictions are borne out, then we can consider the model useful.

No-where does this assume knowledge of how nature works, or that the underlying structure of the universe is something logically equivalent to being analytic

So, what you are really observing is that models based on analytic functions are *useful*.