# Infinite differentiablity in Nature?

Tags: differential-geometry, navier-stokes

I'm working through understanding Clay Institute's paper addressing their Navier-Stokes millennium prize.

I can't find any resources online stating if there are any infinitely differentiable examples in nature.

I looked up vortexes and found the curl is constant inside the vortex, but discontinuous outside of it, which would, I think, deny the vortex to be able to solve the problem for an incompressible fluid. This is also the case with EM fields which are "almost" completely differentiable.

However, is gravity infinitely differentiable? Newton's or GR? Is even the law of motion infinitely differentiable? I haven't found any hits on duckduckgo.

Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400379) for the case of GR

Comment: It seems that physics has many examples of smooth equations, yet reality is different.  Both of these is what I needed.  Thank you.